# run .bat on remote computer from .net

Tags: .net, remote-access, batch-file

What is the best way to run .bat file from .NET on remote computer which is not in my local network. It should be secure connection, so the way I'm thinking about is using SSH. Does Windows built in Telnet provide security? Or any other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options come to mind:

1. [Powershell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553)

Answer (score 0):

Create a secured web application on the target machine and implement a command launching the bat. Avoid a "can launch anything" solution even with a secured channel.

Comment: It requires a web server on each target machine, it's a little 'heavy' to run one .bat file. I think that there is more easy way should be exist

Comment: You can heven self host a WCF service. I'm courious to see other solutions.